# How can i unload effect.min.js file?

Tags: functions, jquery, optimization, jquery-ui

I'm currently working on optimizing the speed of my WordPress site, and i successfully unloaded some unnecessary files, but there is one i can't seem to remove which is:

**https://domain.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/effect.min.js?ver=1.11.4**

Is there a way to prevent this file from loading by adding a php code inside **functions.php**?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove Effect Core the you have to remove depended scripts too. Follow this to remove them:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_jquery_effects', 100 );
function remove_jquery_effects()
{
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-core' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-blind' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-bounce' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-clip' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-drop' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-explode' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-fade' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-fold' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-highlight' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-pulsate' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-scale' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-shake' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-slide' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-effects-transfer' );
}
```

Add this to your `functions.php` file. It's remove the script from front end.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way like the method you have shown above for unloading specific css files and js files loaded by a theme that have different paths?

Comment: You can always dequeue and deregister css and js file if that is added using wp_equeue_script. All you need to figure out it the `key` . You cen find the keys by checking theme files.

Comment: It did work, i inspected the files and i got the ID like you said. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Good to hear it helped you!